# Como criar um navegador básico somente para executar códigos JavaScript embutidos

Tags: javascript, c#, vb.net

Como posso criar um navegador básico em VB.NET ou C# e executar código JavaScript dentro dele, e sem mostrar o código? Pois eu queria esconder meu código JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar um projeto WPF em C# e usar

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="MeuNavegador" Source="MeuDocumento.html" />
```

para manipular o DOM e chamar Javascript

você pode usar o [método](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491132%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
WebBrowser.InvokeScript
```

Exemplo:
Aqui está o código Javascript dentro do HTML.

```
function resize() {
    alert('Hello World');
}
```

No WPF chame:

```
MeuNavegador.Document.InvokeScript("resize");
```

*Durante a Microsoft BUILD 2018 foi anunciado que haverá a possibilidade de utilizar o EDGE como WebBrowser no WPF, WinForms, etc.*